# Need help in discerning whether or not this is a joke question or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recursion

Just a few moments ago, I have asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020820/need-some-advice-on-this-elementary-number-theory-proof) regarding a proof that my math teacher asked me to solve. But it turned out to be a joke; he was asking me to solve the ABC conjecture, which apparently is a known open question in the math community. Now I have another extra credit proof(my teacher gave 5 of them; hopefully they aren't all just jokes), but I'm having trouble figuring out if this is just another joke question or not. It is as follows:

> Consider a sequence $(a_n)$ that has an initial value of $a_0=k$, where $k$ is a positive integer. Every term after that is then defined recursively as follows:$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{a_{n-1}}2&\text{if }a_{n-1}\equiv0\pmod2\\3a_{n-1}+1&\text{if }a_{n-1}\equiv1\pmod2\end{cases}$$Prove or disprove the statement that there are infinitely many values for $k$ such that $(a_n)$ will reach $1$ at some point.

My initial thought was to try out small values for $k$. I first tested $k=3$, which produces the following sequence:$$3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1$$
I noticed that if the sequence reaches any power of $2$, then it will eventually reach $1$. But after this, I don't know what I can do. I suppose I can try to find an explicit formula for this recursive sequence but I feel like that would be a hard task.

This problem is pretty easy to understand, yet the proof still eludes me. I didn't spend too much time on this, thinking it might be another joke, but I'm not sure if that's the case here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Collatz's Conjecture, unproven. We are seeing a pattern here.

Comment: You have a horrible teacher.

Comment: This is another known open problem, the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), also known as the "$3n+1$ problem."

Comment: I wouldn't call the teacher horrible from this alone... I loved my teacher for introducing me to various open problems which I tried my hand at myself as well, though at least my teacher made it clear that they were still open and that it wasn't expected to be possible to prove at our level.

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know; I had a suspicion this was the case.

Comment: For instance, the three towers of Hanoi problem is a well known problem with a relatively trivial solution... but change it to four towers and the problem suddenly becomes quite difficult.  Trying to come up with an algorithm, a method of counting the number of steps taken by the algorithm, and attempting to prove no better algorithm exists was quite difficult challenge that I ultimately failed at, but a very enjoyable experience.  Getting to see where my attempts had gone wrong was very enlightening.

Comment: I am waiting for RH (actually was hoping it would come first as a millennium problem).

Comment: @Randall  Horrible teachers are those who don't teach. This one is a bit clownish, but OP is  in safe hands here on MSE!

Comment: OK, OP has a teacher with a horrible sense of humor.  How's that?

Comment: @player3236 Following this pattern, next homework will be to prove that an even number greater than $2$ can be expressed as the sum of two primes. And for Friday to prove that there are no positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $a^n+b^n=c^n,n>2$ in less than $220$ words

Comment: @Raffaele Do you really believe these problems come from "a teacher"? I don't see any evidence for this (the promised screen shots never came so far - see the comment to the first question, the abc-conjecture).

Comment: @Raffaele Gonna miss the deadline on these ones, I'm afraid.

Comment: @DietrichBurde A troll on MSE. Why?

Comment: These are the screenshots you are looking for, uploaded onto imgur: imgur.com/a/QRQzN7w.

Comment: @Randall  Try reading the question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People aren't reading the question carefully.  This is NOT the Collatz conjecture, but a different problem about the Collatz sequence.   The question given is easy to solve:   Consider the infinite set $\{ 2^n | n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It turns out that I did notice the correct thing about the powers of $2$, but I didn't think about the fact that $k\in\{2^n|n=1,2,3,\dots\}$ which results in infinitely many answers.